# Camelize a spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel, spring-boot

We have a spring boot application that is growing in complexity because of integration needs - like send an email after you do this, or broadcast a jms message after you that etc. In looking for some higher level abstractions, I came across apache camel (haven't used camel ever before). The question that I have is what do I do with the spring boot application? The application has the standard spring controllers, services and uses spring-data for connecting to databases. I didn't find much help online on how to merge camel into a spring-boot restful application. Is that even something that is doable or is camel a completely different beast that the spring boot won't fit?

I did read that Camel tightly integrates with Spring, but still I didn't know if 1) Spring Controllers are still something that can be used along with Camel 2) If I can call the other spring beans from camel routes and whether I can call invoke a camel route from a spring bean (sorry if these sound like camel newbie questions to the experts)

As an example of what we have to do:

1. After finishing writing anything to the database about an order, we have to send an email out to the order processing department
2. If someone deletes a particular user address, we have to send to a jms topic so other applications can take action.

Every http request is coming in through the Spring MVC stack today.

Is there a way to "hand-off" the processing to camel after a particular task is complete? (like writing the order to the database successfully via the Spring MVC stack and hand off to camel to send a jms message and do other things)? Or should we completely replace Spring with Camel?

Not sure what the right path is. Can someone please guide us?

Comment: Although you might be able to get Apache Camel worknig with Spring Boot you also might want to try Spring Integration which covers the same things as Apache Camel. Advantage is that Spring Boot already has support for it.

Comment: I have an Apache Camel application that I integrated Spring Boot into. Works great.

Comment: @MattRaible - Can you please share some more details? Do you use Spring's rest controllers at all or is everything done through Camel? How do you go from spring boot to camel and back? Truly appreciate if you could share some more details.

Comment: Everything is done through Camel. I don't have any Spring Controllers, just SOAP services powered by CXF and Camel. Camel and all Spring components are configured with JavaConfig - no XML.

Comment: I wrote a blog post today on integrating Spring Boot into our Camel project. Hope it helps! http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/developing_services_with_apache_camel2

Answer (score 4):

This question is slightly old, but though it was worth mentioning here that Apache Camel now includes a Spring Boot component.

Details can be found here
http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html
and they document an example here
http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot-example.html

Follow this for the current best practice in camelising a spring boot application!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to 
1> define camel routes either in Spring DSL or Java DSL or other means and define it in Spring Application context. 
 
2> And have a class that implements ApplicationContextAware and cache the Spring ApplicationContext in a Static Variable. 
3> For @Controller we can get this static variable and get hold of ApplicationContext . 
4> With the camel context ID we can do a getBean from ApplicationContext. 
5> This is the instance of DefaultCamelContext,with this we can do a createProducer and call camel routes from @Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Like some others mentioned, spring-boot-camel (but use spring-boot-camel-starter as your dependency) works very well and it is really easy to set up.  When you annotate your RouteBuilder extensions and your Processor implementations with @Component, they wire up directly into the context and you are good to go.  Then, you can @Autowire a CamelContext or a ProducerTemplate into your classes and use them as necessary.

You asked about how Controllers can work with Camel, and if you @Autowire any of the things you need (probably a context or a producer template), then the answer is a definite "yes" that you can use them together quite easily.  And when you use spring-web, your context will start and remain running without any additional configuration, etc.

Like Matthew Wells suggested, the links will get you pointed in the right direction.  If you, or others on your team, are at all familiar with Camel, then it will be very easy for you to do what you need to do.  But, ah, I notice that this question is from 2014, and you're probably well past the point of your question.  At least if anyone else stops by this thread, they will have plenty of information to get going.  If you come by and re-visit your question, please let us know how it went for you, and what you ended up doing.  Cheers!